# Grid table to PDF in R - formatting placement on page, and repeating headers/footers

Tags: r, dataframe, formatting, grid, gridextra

I apologize if this has been asked, but I'm unfamiliar with R (much more familiar with Python) and have had trouble searching for it.

I have a table (dataframe) with ~10 columns and dozens to hundreds of rows. I have followed tutorials that answer most of my questions, but can't figure out how to:

1) Move grid table from center of PDF output to top left (with custom-defined margins).

2) Force repeating headers on every page

3) Add repeating footers/footnotes on each page

How can I add those features? For example, with the code:

'''

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
d <- iris[sample(nrow(iris), 187, TRUE),]
tg <- tableGrob(d, rows = seq_len(nrow(d))) 

fullheight <- convertHeight(sum(tg$heights), "cm", valueOnly = TRUE)
margin <- unit(0.51,"in")
margin_cm <- convertHeight(margin, "cm", valueOnly = TRUE)
a4height <- 29.7 - margin_cm
nrows <- nrow(tg)
npages <- ceiling(fullheight / a4height)

heights <- convertHeight(tg$heights, "cm", valueOnly = TRUE) 
rows <- cut(cumsum(heights), include.lowest = FALSE,
            breaks = c(0, cumsum(rep(a4height, npages))))

groups <- split(seq_len(nrows), rows)

gl <- lapply(groups, function(id) tg[id,])

pdf("multipage.pdf", paper = "a4", width = 0, height = 0)
for(page in seq_len(npages)){
  grid.newpage()
  grid.rect(width=unit(21,"cm") - margin,
            height=unit(29.7,"cm")- margin)
  grid.draw(gl[[page]])
}

dev.off()
```

'''

Thanks for any help anyone can give, or links anyone can provide to where these questions are already answered.

Comment: You should probably look into `rmarkdown` for those more advanced features...